# MySQL: Get average of datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table having fields id, cust_id, ord_id, ord_date(datetime datatype). In table, I have data like this..

```
id  cust_id  ord_id      ord_date              prod_id
1   1         1          2015-12-01 00:00:00   1
2   1         1          2015-12-01 00:00:00   2
3   1         1          2015-12-01 00:00:00   3
4   2         1          2015-12-01 00:00:00   1
5   1         3          2015-12-03 00:00:00   1
6   1         3          2015-12-03 00:00:00   2
7   1         2          2015-12-02 00:00:00   1
8   3         1          2015-12-03 00:00:00   1
9   3         1          2015-12-03 00:00:00   2
10  2         2          2015-12-07 00:00:00   1
12  2         2          2015-12-07 00:00:00   2
13  3         2          2015-12-10 00:00:00   1
14  1         4          2015-12-12 00:00:00   1
15  3         3          2015-12-15 00:00:00   1
```

I have to get data of average order time of each customers with last ord_id (max ord_id) and should be order by cust_id ASC, ord_id DESC.
I want output like this using MYSQL query.

```
cust_id  ord_id    ord_date               ord_avg_day
1        4         2015-12-12 00:00:00     3
2        2         2015-12-07 00:00:00     3
3        3         2015-12-15 00:00:00     4
```

I have tried this, but failed as it shows average time 0.

```
SELECT cust_id, ord_id, ord_date, AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(ord_date)) AS ord_avg_day FROM tableName GROUP BY cust_id, ord_id ORDER BY cust_id, ord_id DESC
```

I know that it will be easy using normalization. But I have no option for it. I have to work with only this table.

If anyone knows the solution, then answer will be appreciate.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "average order time"? I don't understand how your desired results come about

Comment: average order time means on average of how many days customer puts an order..

Comment: I still don't understand how you reach that result, maybe you should edit the question to describe in more detail what the orders table does

Comment: `TIME_TO_SEC` just converts the time part of the datetime to a number. All your orders are at time 00:00:00, that's why you get avg = 0.

Comment: @Bramar, I have tried TIME_TO_SEC too. But it results in 0.000. IF time is 00:00:00, then it must be equal to 12:00:00 AM. So it's not wrong.. So I think there is some other problem..

Comment: Here min ord_date is date of #1 row and max ord_date is date of #14 row. Just to remind if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a simple way to do it. There are some output that you not using. You can delete it. Its only to test.

```
SELECT 
  cust_id
  , count(*) AS ord_id
  , min(ord_date) AS first_order
  , max(ord_date) AS last_order
  , (DATEDIFF(max(ord_date) , min(ord_date)) ) / (count(*)-1) AS ord_avg_day
FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM myorder
      GROUP BY ord_date,cust_id
    ) AS tmp
GROUP BY cust_id;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| cust_id | ord_id | first_order         | last_order          | ord_avg_day |
+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|       1 |      4 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00 | 2015-12-12 00:00:00 |      3.6667 |
|       2 |      2 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00 | 2015-12-07 00:00:00 |      6.0000 |
|       3 |      3 | 2015-12-03 00:00:00 | 2015-12-15 00:00:00 |      6.0000 |
+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have correct a error.
Please let me know if it works for you